# Case insensitive duplicate record insertion restriction Node MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert

I wanted to know if when inserting a record in a mongodb collection, if the unique key already has the case-insensitive value, then mongodb doesn't insert the record, but returns a duplicate error.

Example:

`1. Adds { name: "wow" } // inserts
2. Adds { name: "wOW" } // error: duplicate record found.`

I've tried this, but it doesn't work (sorry I am new to mongo and don't understand NoSQL that much).

```
let data = { 
    name: new RegExp('^' + params.input.name + '$', 'i')
};

db.collection(collectionName).insertOne(data, function(err, res) {
    db.close();

    if (err) return callback(err, false);
    return callback(false, res);
}
```

I hope there is a solution to this problem, without me having to hit the database collection just to check if a duplicate exists.

Comment: Do You need field name as the unique key? Because you can use _id as a unique key. I wrote an answer but I deleted because I added a field _id as the unique key.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-case-insensitive/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation-document-fields
Maybe you need use strength = 3

Comment: @Cuchu Thanks man, I'll give this a read. Actually we want the name of the department to be unique per institution, therefore leading us to use this approach rather than going for _id field.

Comment: Well, another alternative to insert documents is updateOne [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/). I use update and really work fine for me when I need dump a lot of data.